# Polynomials Passing Through $n(\in\mathbb{N})$ Points in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, coordinate-systems

Conjecture $1:$ There is exactly one polynomial of degree $n-1$ passing through $n(\in\mathbb{N})$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Conjecture $2:$ There are infinitely many polynomials of degree $n$ passing through $n(\in\mathbb{N})$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2.$

These two statements are easy to prove for $n=1,$ and $n=2.$ But, for $n≥3,$ the proof method I'm using gets a little tedious. Basically, I formed equations and solved them to get the values of the coefficients. Is there any way to prove this for a general $n\in\mathbb{N}?$

Note: I am only considering polynomials in one variable that have real coefficients, and accept real inputs. Moreover, when I say that $p,$ a polynomial passes through $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2,$ I mean that $p(x_0)=y_0.$ The points I'm considering have distinct $x$ coordinates.

Comment: What do you mean by *a polynomial passing through the point $(x_0,y_0)$*? Do you mean that for a polynomial $p(x,y)$ in two variables we have $p(x_0,y_0)=0$? Or do you mean that for a polynomial $p(x)$ in single variable we have $p(x_0)=y_0$? The answer will be different for different interpretations, so please clarify. In the question body.

Comment: I mean that $p(x_0)=y_0.$ I will edit this in.

Comment: For the latter interpretation it is necessary to require that the $x$-coordinates of the points be distinct, for otherwise we don't get any such polynomials. Since you did not specify that either, I had to ask for a clarification rather than simply interpret the question the way I would expect a high school student / calculus student to interpret it.

Comment: If so, then (assuming the $x$-coordinates are distinct), this is more or less a FAQ, and the answer is given by the [Lagrange interpolating polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). Conjecture 2 coming from our ability to specify the value of the polynomial at some extra point any which way we prefer.

Comment: Conjecture 1 is false as stated.  It needs to be a unique polynomial of degree less than or equal to $n-1$.  Simple case:  Take a bunch of points on a horizontal line, they form a degree 0 polynomial